# Azure SDK C# - Create VM from Image with specified disk type(Standard SSD)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are using the Azure SDK in a C# .NET Core application to create Azure VMs on demand. At the moment, the VMs are created using standard HDD, but we would like to use Standard SSD instead. However, can't find anything in the documentation pointing to how you''d achieve this.

The code we are using is essentially this:

```
var windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.Define("myWindowsVM")
    .WithRegion(Region.US_EAST)
    .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
    .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
    .WithPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
    .WithNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress("mywindowsvmdns")
    .WithPopularWindowsImage(KnownWindowsVirtualMachineImage.WINDOWS_SERVER_2012_R2_DATACENTER)
    .WithAdminUserName("user")
    .WithPassword(password)
    .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardD2sV3)
    .Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SSD is currently denoted by the **"E"** series machines. Note that few of the disk sizes are currently in preview. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-types#standard-ssd) doc for all the available sizes.

Looking through the [Azure virtual machine libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/0901b9aeaccf2b1e505fca8f1c744d61d9188e34/src/ResourceManagement/Compute/Generated/Models/VirtualMachineSizeTypes.cs#L108-L123), these are the supported VM size types as of today:
[image: Supported VM size types]

Therefore, the following code should work:

```
 IVirtualMachine windowsVM = azure.VirtualMachines.Define(vmName)
            .WithRegion(location)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(groupName)
            .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
            .WithPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
            .WithNewPrimaryPublicIPAddress("MyIPAddressLabel")
            .WithPopularWindowsImage(KnownWindowsVirtualMachineImage.WindowsServer2012R2Datacenter)
            .WithAdminUsername("UserName")
            .WithAdminPassword("Password")
            .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardE2V3)
            .Create();
```

For more info on Standard SSD disks, please take a look at the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/faq-for-disks#standard-ssd-disks).

Hope this helps!